# Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table:

Tags: 8

I'm getting a strange error with my Drupal site. The error is as follows:

```
Drupal\Core\Database\DatabaseExceptionWrapper: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table: router: SELECT name, route, fit FROM {router} WHERE pattern_outline IN ( :patterns__0 ) AND number_parts >= :count_parts; Array ( [:count_parts] => 0 [:patterns__0] => / ) in Drupal\Core\Routing\RouteProvider->getRoutesByPath() (line 344 of core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/RouteProvider.php).
```

I don't know much about what's causing the error. I took a look at the file the error references, but I can't figure out what to change.

Here are the steps I took that led up to the error:

1. I started with a Drupal 7 website.
2. I deleted all of my files from the website directory.
   Note: The "sites" directory would not delete no matter how many times I tried.
3. I uploaded my Drupal 8 release candidate 1 hoping that that new "sites" directory would overwrite the old one.
4. I reloaded my website page and was presented with error above.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does the table exist in the database?

Comment: My database is empty. I thought I was supposed to start with an empty database.

Comment: Have you installed the site or are you getting this error while installing?

Comment: I haven't yet installed the site.

Comment: It'd probably be best to open a bug report on drupal.org in that case, if you can't get past the first pages of the installation that's a pretty big problem; you shouldn't be in a position to need to change core code just to get an install working. If it's not, and you can edit the question to list out all the steps you've taken to get to the point you're at, someone might be able to spot where it's gone wrong

Comment: I figure that a bug report will take a while to be processed and the website I'm doing needs to be done as soon as possible. I'll list the steps I've taken instead.

Comment: If it is a bug I'm afraid drupal.org is the only option, we don't take them here. But let's hope it's not and these steps will shed some light

Comment: Ah ok, definitely see the problem there - Drupal 8 isn't an update, it's a brand new system; you need to _migrate_ your D7 site to it. The docs are [here](https://www.drupal.org/upgrade/migrate), they should contain everything you need

Comment: Well, I suppose it's too late to do anything now, considering I already deleted the old site.

Comment: @Clive: That last comment there is the only valid answer and should be one :). You need to make a new installation in a new database and then connect the migrate tools to your old one. But it might be a bit early for that, especially if you use any contrib module.

Comment: Guess I was hoping you'd come along and say "actually there _is_ a way to upgrade..." @Berdir ;)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you've gone down the wrong path by deleting your existing site. Hopefully you have a backup you can restore from...

Drupal 8 isn't an update, it's a brand new system; you need to migrate your D7 site to it.

The docs are [here](https://www.drupal.org/upgrade/migrate), they should contain everything you need

Comment: Nope. No backup. I thought you had to start from a blank slate, which is why I deleted the whole site. Oops.

Comment: Since I deleted the whole thing, how do I fix this problem in order to start from scratch?

Comment: Does anyone know how I can start from scratch?